# Acronym hyperlink with special color only at first occurence

Tags: acronyms, hyperlink

I am using the `acronym` package for creating a list of abbreviations in my thesis. Whenever I enter an acronym in text, I would like to change the color of the created hyperlink to the normal black text color. The first occurrence should keep its special color.

I assume this might work with `\AC@hyperlink`, but I could not figure out how.

Help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: IIRC, colorlinks is implemented by using \textcolor, which you could do yourself.  The tricky bit is locating the first occurrence.